# How to position this alert component at the top of the screen?

Tags: css, reactjs, frontend, jsx, react-bootstrap

I want this alert danger component at the top of the screen and infront of any other text.but its not working
what part of the code will i have to change?

```
import React from 'react'
import Alert from 'react-bootstrap/Alert'

export const ErrorAlert = () => {
  return (
    <div style={{postition:"absolute",top:"0"}}>
    <Alert variant="danger"   dismissible>
    <Alert.Heading>Oh snap! You got an error!</Alert.Heading>
    <p>
      Change this and that and try agasdsdsdin. Duis mollis, est non commodo
      luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit.
      Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.
    </p>
  </Alert>
  </div>
  )
}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you are expecting toast kind of thing

Comment: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/toasts/ try this module for that

Answer (score 1):

you have entered the wrong style, please copy the below code and paste it inside your component.

```js
import React from 'react'
import Alert from 'react-bootstrap/Alert'

export const ErrorAlert = () => {
  return (
    <div style={{ position: "absolute", top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, zIndex: 999 }}>
    <Alert variant="danger"   dismissible>
    <Alert.Heading>Oh snap! You got an error!</Alert.Heading>
    <p>
      Change this and that and try agasdsdsdin. Duis mollis, est non commodo
      luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit.
      Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.
    </p>
  </Alert>
  </div>
  )
}
```